# Hierarchical database (IMS DB) data retrieval method

Tags: database, mainframe, data-retrieval, ims-db

IMS db has a 'tree' like database structure, which everything is connected to the root node, similar to a binary search tree. I tried to find a good resource about how data access is happening in IMS db, but it seems IBM doesn't provide a clear understanding of how its systems work. I'm wondering how a specific node in this database is found, considering the databases with this structure are among the largest ones in the industry. In a binary search tree, the data is found by comparing the children of a parent node. Is this the same method of data retrieval in IMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [this RedBook](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg245352.pdf) (SG245352), specifically figures 26 and 27, and the accompanying explanation.  The publication is almost 20 years old, but IMS itself is almost 50 years old.

[image: figure 26]

[image: figure 27]